# Function returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript

My function returns "undefined", when I am waiting "result". What is a problem?

```
getUserDictionary = (user_id) => {
  connection.connection.query("SELECT eng_word, ru_word FROM `dictionary` where user_id="+user_id,
   function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results);
      return results;
    });
}

console.log(getUserDictionary(1));
```

"results" shows what I want (no problem with Data base connection). 
But last console.log with function returns undefined

Comment: SQL injection vulnerability. Surprised no one has mentioned it yet.

Answer (score 1):

### You are leaving yourself wide open to a SQL injection attack

Do not do this: `"SELECT eng_word, ru_word FROM dictionary where user_id="+user_id`

If this is just a pet project, fine, but if you're opening it up to the internet anyone could erase your database. Use prepared statements instead. If you are using [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) you can drop this in as a replacement for your current query:

```
connection.query('SELECT eng_word, ru_word FROM dictionary WHERE user_id = ?', [user_id], function (error, results, fields) {
```

### Anyways...

Your problem is that `connection.connection.query()` is an asynchronous function. If you would like it to behave synchronously, you can use the `async/await` pattern supported in ES6. Otherwise, you can structure your code to act *in response* to the return from `query()`.

Here is what it would look like using `async/await`:

```
getUserDictionary = (user_id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.connection.query("blah blah blah",
      function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        console.log(results);
        resolve(results);
      });
  });
};
```

Which you can use like

```
async () => {
  let results = await getUserDictionary(0);
  console.log(results);
}
```

Comment: The await needs to be inside an `async` function to work